# opacidade, transparência no input

Tags: html, css3, input, opacity

Olá, estou começando a aprender html e css. Estou querendo fazer um efeito no cadastro do meu site da seguinte forma. Adiciono um input e enquanto esse input esta vazio ele permanece opaco, quando a pessoa digita ele perde a propriedade opaco e fica visível. Tem como fazer isso somente com o CSS ?

Segue meu código, consegui torna-lo opaco em estado vazio e perder a propriedade quando em foco, porem depois de digitar ele torna a ficar opaco. Pesquisando eu entendi que o input pertence aos void e por isso ele torna opaco novamente pois ele não valida os valores.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com essa questão, desde já fico grato.

```
    input:empty {
    opacity: 0.1;
    }

    input:focus {
        opacity: 1;
    }

<input  type="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trabalhando apenas com CSS e HTML vejo da seguinte forma:

```css
input:empty {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="something">
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Um abraço